# Mongo DB : remove document from collection

Tags: mongodb

Here is one of my document of my collection "entities", I can't figure out how to remove it.

```
 {
    "_id" : {
        "id" : "sensors:StreetLight2",
        "type" : "sensors",
        "servicePath" : "/egmmqttpath"
    },
    "attrNames" : [
        "TimeInstant",
        "PING_status"
    ],
    "attrs" : {
        "PING_status" : {
            "value" : "delivered but no respond",
            "type" : "string",
            "md" : [
                {
                    "name" : "TimeInstant",
                    "type" : "ISO8601",
                    "value" : "2015-11-20T09:02:53.114688"
                }
            ],
            "creDate" : 1448010161,
            "modDate" : 1448010172
        },
        "TimeInstant" : {
            "value" : "2015-11-20T09:02:53.114834",
            "type" : "ISO8601",
            "creDate" : 1448010122,
            "modDate" : 1448010172
        }
    },
    "creDate" : 1448010122,
    "modDate" : 1448010172
}
```

Any ideas? how can I remove the above document? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your deletion criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/):

> db.collection.remove()
>
> Removes documents from a collection.

**1) By _ID:** Since _ID is unique.

```
db.entities.remove( {"_id" :
    {
        "id" : "sensors:StreetLight2",
        "type" : "sensors",
        "servicePath" : "/egmmqttpath"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the _id to remove it.

```
db.entities.remove({
    "_id" : {
        "id" : "sensors:StreetLight2",
        "type" : "sensors",
        "servicePath" : "/egmmqttpath"
    }
})
```

Comment: Wow, what's going on with downvoting correct answers in this thread and upvoting wrong answers? This is crazy.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I understand your pain. Don't understand how some generic comments like "db.entities.remove(query)" got 3 votes and I got -2. If you find out what's wrong with my comment please let me know. Happy  to remove or amend it.

Comment: Your answer looks completely correct to me, which is why I upvoted it.

Comment: @VedantKekan please flag this question (or some of its answers) for moderator's attention.

Answer (score -2):

In [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/) you should use [.remove()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/):

```js
db.entities.remove(
{
    "_id" :
    {
        "id" : "sensors:StreetLight2",
        "type" : "sensors",
        "servicePath" : "/egmmqttpath"
    }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

remove document in mongodb

```
query = {"_id": <value of _id>}

db.entities.remove(query)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
db.entities.remove(
 "_id" : {
"id" : "sensors:StreetLight2",
        "type" : "sensors",
        "servicePath" : "/egmmqttpath""id" : "sensors:StreetLight2"
    }
)
```

you can also take any key-value pair from documents for remove

you can refer these links for better understanding

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-documents/

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/

Comment: Wow, this is so wrong. You have two errors in your syntax. But even after you fix them, this will not remove the document. You're not matching a correct `_id` document.

Comment: you can edit it if you feel syntax error and if you want to contribute in open-source community than support people  instead of down voting

Comment: I have contributed by presenting a correct answer that I have verified to work. The answer was downvoted.

Comment: 1) You need to pass an object. Object literals are always surrounded by curly braces. You did not specify an object literal correctly, so you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: 2) You cannot match a subdocument on a single field without using [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/). Hence, your query will not remove the document in question. Its `_id` contains three fields, not one.